# crypto.subtle.importKey in Chrome throws a DOMException, while Firefox works well

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cryptography, domexception

I'm trying to import an ECDSA public key as follows:

```
ua8 = new Uint8Array( [48, 86, 48, 16, 6, 4, 43, 129, 4, 112, 6, 8, 42, 134, 72, 206, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4, 124, 78, 186, 4, 136, 215, 226, 113, 200, 80, 93, 199, 105, 63, 47, 60, 193, 162, 180, 226, 160, 164, 9, 183, 122, 42, 97, 201, 99, 128, 54, 227, 193, 220, 229, 75, 186, 223, 201, 227, 229, 159, 159, 67, 205, 3, 126, 74, 211, 202, 122, 66, 185, 150, 74, 152, 192, 177, 81, 155, 106, 237, 212, 146] );
crypto.subtle.importKey( "spki", ua8, { name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256", }, false, ["verify"] );
```

In Firefox, this works well, but in Chrome I get a DOMException.

I want it to work in both browsers. How can I fix it?

Comment: thank you for editing the text. i am not a good english writer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Chromium WebCrypto documentation](https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto#TOC-Supported-key-formats):

> Chromium's WebCrypto implementation supports all of the key formats - "raw", "spki", "pkcs8", "jwk", with the following caveats:

> - There are differences in DER key format handling between Web Crypto implementations. Where possible for compatibility prefer using "raw" keys or "jwk" which have better interoperability.

> - When importing/exporting "spki" and "pkcs8" formats, the only OIDs supported by Chromiumare those recognized by OpenSSL/BoringSSL.

in particular, it says that:

> - Importing ECDH keys [does not accept id-ecDH](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532728). The OID must instead be id-ecPublicKey (This can cause problems importing keys generated by Firefox; use "raw" EC keys as a workaround; Chromium in this case is not spec compliant)

<sup>(The bug tracker link is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error, but that might be temporary.)</sup>

[Looking at your key in an ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#3056301006042B81047006082A8648CE3D030107034200047C4EBA0488D7E271C8505DC7693F2F3CC1A2B4E2A0A409B77A2A61C9638036E3C1DCE54BBADFC9E3E59F9F43CD037E4AD3CA7A42B9964A98C0B1519B6AEDD492), it contains the following data:

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.3.132.112
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 prime256v1 (ANSI X9.62 named elliptic curve)
    BIT STRING (520 bit) 0000010001111100010011101011101000000100100010001101011111100010011100…
```

The object identifier 1.3.132.112 is precisely the "id-ecDH" identifier that Chrome does not recognize.  For what it's worth, [a key exported from Chrome](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#3059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107034200049CB0CF69303DAFC761D4E4687B4ECF039E6D34AB964AF80810D8D558A4A8D6F72D51233A1788920A86EE08A1962C79EFA317FB7879E297DAD2146DB995FA1C78) instead has the OID 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ("ecPublicKey").

As the linked documentation page suggests, as a workaround you may wish to switch from the "spki" format to "raw" (or to ["jwk"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517), which is JSON-based).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `keyUsages` to `[]` should solve your problem. From my understanding, only the private key should have a 'usage'.