# DOMException when importing a pem formatted public RSA key using the WebCrypto API

Tags: javascript, rsa, pem, webcrypto-api

I may be missing some security concern that prevents the browser from importing a public key file into a CryptoKey object, but I can't see anything mentioned in the docs. The browser produces a "DOMException" with no message attached.

I am using a helper library "OpenCrypto" to simplify the key management process, but I received the same error when I was using the WebCrypto APIs directly (which prompted me to use a helper library, to ensure it wasn't just me misusing the API).

```
async importKey() {
    try {
        let pem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq3GvsQ5+vT+lkuGb7PP6
        slV5mNyOAQo5rhInuDMFkyJOnwIDLzOQ7tLe4ApDPt2CmuRG+qpMaul+IYPBk6Ts
        9YPdvvVh5lohiDRN7ny3Sd5uwUy4Ea/NkY62lui4zDFnUDMH8pAUcJWQW4zKloRI
        k2EsXR5A5dqOq4wv2+I76Ax9lK2qYkQBZ8ZqeePPMYU1N0lETzCgDW/FqQEk6m81
        2c8LnF2bhnrjFJ2k0lTDVx4TwvEUOEg6TbFah+PNe8CFN/cJsHMxlr4StV6nwpZu
        n62YSXo9KskLmSRNhGKUS+oNEzTeLRyNfpZb3WQFOjqlgqJFW1xp1KfEdqFk+37z
        HwIDAQAB
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

        let key = await this.#crypt.pemPublicToCrypto(pem, { name: 'RSA-PSS', usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error importing key`, error);
    }
}
```

The public key was produced using the Node JS's implementation of the WebCrypto API (crypto.webcrypto), and then I simply copied and pasted the content into this function to try it. Running this function in node imports fine. Running it in the browser produces the  DOMException.

Here is the relevant code from OpenCrypto's source:

```
const cryptoLib = window.crypto || window.msCrypto
const cryptoApi = cryptoLib.subtle || cryptoLib.webkitSubtle

//... other code removed for clarity


  /**
   * Method that converts asymmetric public key from PEM to CryptoKey format
   * @param {String} publicKey default: "undefined"
   * @param {Object} options default: depends on algorithm below
   * -- ECDH: { name: 'ECDH', usages: [], isExtractable: true }
   * -- ECDSA: { name: 'ECDSA', usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true }
   * -- RSA-OAEP: { name: 'RSA-OAEP', hash: { name: 'SHA-512' }, usages: ['encrypt', 'wrapKey'], isExtractable: true }
   * -- RSA-PSS: { name: 'RSA-PSS', hash: { name: 'SHA-512' }, usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true }
   */
  pemPublicToCrypto (pem, options) {
    const self = this

    if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
      options = {}
    }

    options.isExtractable = (typeof options.isExtractable !== 'undefined') ? options.isExtractable : true

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof pem !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected input of pem to be a String')
      }

      if (typeof options.isExtractable !== 'boolean') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.isExtractable to be a Boolean')
      }

      pem = pem.replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '')
      pem = pem.replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '')

      const b64 = self.removeLines(pem)
      const arrayBuffer = self.base64ToArrayBuffer(b64)
      const hex = self.arrayBufferToHexString(arrayBuffer)
      const keyOptions = {}

      if (hex.includes(EC_OID)) {
        options.name = (typeof options.name !== 'undefined') ? options.name : 'ECDH'

        if (typeof options.name !== 'string') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name to be a String')
        }

        let curve = null
        if (hex.includes(P256_OID)) {
          curve = 'P-256'
        } else if (hex.includes(P384_OID)) {
          curve = 'P-384'
        } else if (hex.includes(P521_OID)) {
          curve = 'P-521'
        }

        if (options.name === 'ECDH') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : []
        } else if (options.name === 'ECDSA') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : ['verify']
        } else {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name is not a valid algorithm name')
        }

        if (typeof options.usages !== 'object') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.usages to be an Array')
        }

        keyOptions.name = options.name
        keyOptions.namedCurve = curve
      } else if (hex.includes(RSA_OID)) {
        options.name = (typeof options.name !== 'undefined') ? options.name : 'RSA-OAEP'
        options.hash = (typeof options.hash !== 'undefined') ? options.hash : 'SHA-512'

        if (typeof options.name !== 'string') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name to be a String')
        }

        if (typeof options.hash !== 'string') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.hash to be a String')
        }

        if (options.name === 'RSA-OAEP') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : ['encrypt', 'wrapKey']
        } else if (options.name === 'RSA-PSS') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : ['verify']
        } else {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name is not a valid algorithm name')
        }

        if (typeof options.usages !== 'object') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.usages to be an Array')
        }

        keyOptions.name = options.name
        keyOptions.hash = {}
        keyOptions.hash.name = options.hash
      } else {
        throw new TypeError('Expected input of pem is not a valid public key')
      }

      cryptoApi.importKey(
        'spki',
        arrayBuffer,
        keyOptions,
        options.isExtractable,
        options.usages
      ).then(importedPublicKey => {
        resolve(importedPublicKey)
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
  }
```

The error is thrown by the `SubtleCrypto.importKey()` function.

I have tried ECDSA and RSA-PSS keys in case either were incompatible, but both produce the same error.

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867655/crypto-subtle-importkey-in-chrome-throws-a-domexception-while-firefox-works-wel see if this helps

Comment: https://github.com/gchiappe/angular-web-crypto/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply caused by the indentation of the key.

This leads to a corruption during the coversion from PEM to DER: In [`pemPublicToCrypto()`](https://github.com/safebash/opencrypto/blob/main/src/OpenCrypto.js#L642) the line breaks are removed in the line `const b64 = self.removeLines(pem)`. However, this does not remove possible spaces or tabs, so they are included in the data during the subsequent conversion to an `ArrayBuffer` with `const arrayBuffer = self.base64ToArrayBuffer(b64)`, which corrupts the data.

So the solution is to omit the indentation or remove the indentation, e.g. with `pem.replace(/(\s)[ \t]+/g, '$1')`:

```js
async function importKey() {
  var c = new OpenCrypto();
  try {  

    // 
    // Without indentation: Works
    //
    var pem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq3GvsQ5+vT+lkuGb7PP6
slV5mNyOAQo5rhInuDMFkyJOnwIDLzOQ7tLe4ApDPt2CmuRG+qpMaul+IYPBk6Ts
9YPdvvVh5lohiDRN7ny3Sd5uwUy4Ea/NkY62lui4zDFnUDMH8pAUcJWQW4zKloRI
k2EsXR5A5dqOq4wv2+I76Ax9lK2qYkQBZ8ZqeePPMYU1N0lETzCgDW/FqQEk6m81
2c8LnF2bhnrjFJ2k0lTDVx4TwvEUOEg6TbFah+PNe8CFN/cJsHMxlr4StV6nwpZu
n62YSXo9KskLmSRNhGKUS+oNEzTeLRyNfpZb3WQFOjqlgqJFW1xp1KfEdqFk+37z
HwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
    console.log("Key without indentation:") 
    var key = await c.pemPublicToCrypto(pem, { name: 'RSA-PSS', usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true });
    console.log(key);  
    
    // 
    // With indentation and space/tab removal: Works
    //
    var pem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq3GvsQ5+vT+lkuGb7PP6
    slV5mNyOAQo5rhInuDMFkyJOnwIDLzOQ7tLe4ApDPt2CmuRG+qpMaul+IYPBk6Ts
    9YPdvvVh5lohiDRN7ny3Sd5uwUy4Ea/NkY62lui4zDFnUDMH8pAUcJWQW4zKloRI
    k2EsXR5A5dqOq4wv2+I76Ax9lK2qYkQBZ8ZqeePPMYU1N0lETzCgDW/FqQEk6m81
    2c8LnF2bhnrjFJ2k0lTDVx4TwvEUOEg6TbFah+PNe8CFN/cJsHMxlr4StV6nwpZu
    n62YSXo9KskLmSRNhGKUS+oNEzTeLRyNfpZb3WQFOjqlgqJFW1xp1KfEdqFk+37z
    HwIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
    console.log("Key with indentation and space/tab removal:") 
    var key = await c.pemPublicToCrypto(pem.replace(/(\s)[ \t]+/g, '$1'), { name: 'RSA-PSS', usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true });
    console.log(key);  
    
    //
    // With indentation: Doesn't work
    //
    var pem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq3GvsQ5+vT+lkuGb7PP6
    slV5mNyOAQo5rhInuDMFkyJOnwIDLzOQ7tLe4ApDPt2CmuRG+qpMaul+IYPBk6Ts
    9YPdvvVh5lohiDRN7ny3Sd5uwUy4Ea/NkY62lui4zDFnUDMH8pAUcJWQW4zKloRI
    k2EsXR5A5dqOq4wv2+I76Ax9lK2qYkQBZ8ZqeePPMYU1N0lETzCgDW/FqQEk6m81
    2c8LnF2bhnrjFJ2k0lTDVx4TwvEUOEg6TbFah+PNe8CFN/cJsHMxlr4StV6nwpZu
    n62YSXo9KskLmSRNhGKUS+oNEzTeLRyNfpZb3WQFOjqlgqJFW1xp1KfEdqFk+37z
    HwIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

    console.log("Key with indentation:");  
    var key = await c.pemPublicToCrypto(pem, { name: 'RSA-PSS', usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true });
    console.log(key);  
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error importing key`, error);
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2016 SafeBash
 * Cryptography consultant: Andrew Kozlik, Ph.D.
 *
 */

/**
 * MIT License
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2016 SafeBash
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated
 * documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons
 * to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the
 * Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT
 * NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM,
 * DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
const cryptoLib = window.crypto || window.msCrypto
const cryptoApi = cryptoLib.subtle || cryptoLib.webkitSubtle
const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
const lookup = new Uint8Array(256)

const RSA_OID = '06092a864886f70d010101'
const EC_OID = '06072a8648ce3d0201'
const P256_OID = '06082a8648ce3d030107'
const P384_OID = '06052b81040022'
const P521_OID = '06052b81040023'

class OpenCrypto {
  constructor () {
    for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      lookup[chars.charCodeAt(i)] = i
    }
  }

  /**
   * BEGIN
   * base64-arraybuffer
   * GitHub @niklasvh
   * Copyright (c) 2012 Niklas von Hertzen
   * MIT License
   */
  decodeAb (base64) {
    const len = base64.length
    let bufferLength = base64.length * 0.75
    let p = 0
    let encoded1
    let encoded2
    let encoded3
    let encoded4

    if (base64[base64.length - 1] === '=') {
      bufferLength--
      if (base64[base64.length - 2] === '=') {
        bufferLength--
      }
    }

    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(bufferLength)
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
      encoded1 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i)]
      encoded2 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i + 1)]
      encoded3 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i + 2)]
      encoded4 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i + 3)]

      bytes[p++] = (encoded1 << 2) | (encoded2 >> 4)
      bytes[p++] = ((encoded2 & 15) << 4) | (encoded3 >> 2)
      bytes[p++] = ((encoded3 & 3) << 6) | (encoded4 & 63)
    }

    return arrayBuffer
  }
  /**
   * END
   * base64-arraybuffer
   */

  /**
   * Method for encoding ArrayBuffer to hexadecimal String
   */
  arrayBufferToHexString (arrayBuffer) {
    if (typeof arrayBuffer !== 'object') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected input of arrayBuffer to be an ArrayBuffer Object')
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
    let hexString = ''
    let nextHexByte

    for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      nextHexByte = byteArray[i].toString(16)

      if (nextHexByte.length < 2) {
        nextHexByte = '0' + nextHexByte
      }

      hexString += nextHexByte
    }

    return hexString
  }

  /**
   * Method for decoding base64 String to ArrayBuffer
   */
  base64ToArrayBuffer (b64) {
    if (typeof b64 !== 'string') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected input of b64 to be a Base64 String')
    }

    return this.decodeAb(b64)
  }

  /**
   * Method that removes lines from PEM encoded key
   */
  removeLines (str) {
    return str.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')
  }

  /**
   * Method that converts asymmetric public key from PEM to CryptoKey format
   * @param {String} publicKey default: "undefined"
   * @param {Object} options default: depends on algorithm below
   * -- ECDH: { name: 'ECDH', usages: [], isExtractable: true }
   * -- ECDSA: { name: 'ECDSA', usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true }
   * -- RSA-OAEP: { name: 'RSA-OAEP', hash: { name: 'SHA-512' }, usages: ['encrypt', 'wrapKey'], isExtractable: true }
   * -- RSA-PSS: { name: 'RSA-PSS', hash: { name: 'SHA-512' }, usages: ['verify'], isExtractable: true }
   */
  pemPublicToCrypto (pem, options) {
    const self = this

    if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
      options = {}
    }

    options.isExtractable = (typeof options.isExtractable !== 'undefined') ? options.isExtractable : true

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof pem !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected input of pem to be a String')
      }

      if (typeof options.isExtractable !== 'boolean') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.isExtractable to be a Boolean')
      }

      pem = pem.replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '')
      pem = pem.replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '')

      const b64 = self.removeLines(pem)
      const arrayBuffer = self.base64ToArrayBuffer(b64)
      const hex = self.arrayBufferToHexString(arrayBuffer)
      const keyOptions = {}

      if (hex.includes(EC_OID)) {
        options.name = (typeof options.name !== 'undefined') ? options.name : 'ECDH'

        if (typeof options.name !== 'string') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name to be a String')
        }

        let curve = null
        if (hex.includes(P256_OID)) {
          curve = 'P-256'
        } else if (hex.includes(P384_OID)) {
          curve = 'P-384'
        } else if (hex.includes(P521_OID)) {
          curve = 'P-521'
        }

        if (options.name === 'ECDH') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : []
        } else if (options.name === 'ECDSA') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : ['verify']
        } else {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name is not a valid algorithm name')
        }

        if (typeof options.usages !== 'object') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.usages to be an Array')
        }

        keyOptions.name = options.name
        keyOptions.namedCurve = curve
      } else if (hex.includes(RSA_OID)) {
        options.name = (typeof options.name !== 'undefined') ? options.name : 'RSA-OAEP'
        options.hash = (typeof options.hash !== 'undefined') ? options.hash : 'SHA-512'

        if (typeof options.name !== 'string') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name to be a String')
        }

        if (typeof options.hash !== 'string') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.hash to be a String')
        }

        if (options.name === 'RSA-OAEP') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : ['encrypt', 'wrapKey']
        } else if (options.name === 'RSA-PSS') {
          options.usages = (typeof options.usages !== 'undefined') ? options.usages : ['verify']
        } else {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.name is not a valid algorithm name')
        }

        if (typeof options.usages !== 'object') {
          throw new TypeError('Expected input of options.usages to be an Array')
        }

        keyOptions.name = options.name
        keyOptions.hash = {}
        keyOptions.hash.name = options.hash
      } else {
        throw new TypeError('Expected input of pem is not a valid public key')
      }

      cryptoApi.importKey(
        'spki',
        arrayBuffer,
        keyOptions,
        options.isExtractable,
        options.usages
      ).then(importedPublicKey => {
        resolve(importedPublicKey)
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
(async () => {
    await importKey();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was the problem. If only there was a more useful error message. Trying on Firefox produced a slightly better error message: "DOMException: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements". Which at least tells me the data is the problem. Brave (Chromium based) just gives a generic "DOMException".